# Building binutils - lfs - error while 'make'

Tags: make, lfs

I'm going to build my own Linux from scratch, but I've got an error while running 'make' for binutils in chapter 5 I get some errors. The output of 'make' is here: http://pastebin.com/8aVz6jfd

There is output of version-check.sh

```
enedil@linux-from-scratch:~$ bash version-check.sh 
bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release
/bin/sh -> /bin/dash
Binutils: (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.23.2
bison (GNU Bison) 2.5
/usr/bin/yacc -> /usr/bin/bison.yacc
bzip2,  Version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010.
Coreutils:  8.20
diff (GNU diffutils) 3.2
find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
gawk: not an option: --version
/usr/bin/awk -> /usr/bin/mawk
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3
(Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.17-0ubuntu5) 2.17
grep (GNU grep) 2.14
gzip 1.5
Linux version 3.8.0-31-generic (buildd@panlong) (gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) ) #46-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 10 20:03:44 UTC 2013
m4 (GNU M4) 1.4.16
GNU Make 3.81
patch 2.6.1
Perl version='5.14.2';
GNU sed version 4.2.1
tar (GNU tar) 1.26
s: line 33: makeinfo: command not found
Texinfo: 
xz (XZ Utils) 5.1.0alpha
gcc compilation OK
```

My distro is Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be missing texinfo, which causes the build process to abort (search the log for lines of the form `*** [directory_name] Error X`). It also tells you, that you normally shouldn't need it, unless you modified sources for the info manuals. I assume this is in one of the bootstrapping parts of LFS, since otherwise you should have `makeinfo` available already.

Check what patches you have applied (if any) - they might have modified some of the documentation files thus triggering the rebuild. You may also try to disable manual building (the `configure` script might have an option for that).

Answer (score 0):

You should have included pastebin (make output) info here. But, it does indicate a number of missing things in your [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) build;

```
checking for aclocal... no
checking for autoconf... no
checking for autoheader... no
```

And, the missing *makeinfo*.

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf automake autotools-dev
```

This will give you *aclocal*, *autoconf*, and *autoheader* as per [AUTOTOOLS FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/faq/autotools-faq.html#What-are-the-_0060_0060Autotools_0027_0027_003f). Your make info package is carried by [*textinfo*](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-distributions-5/makeinfo-install-4175638309/) so installing that will solve that problem.

```
sudo apt-get install texinfo
```

After this, try again and post an update.

Comment: Do you realize I had this issue almost 8 years ago?

Comment: I did realize (7 years, 5 months ago to be exact) but as other people work through the problems and use stack exchange, it is best to update the responses and close if possible. 

The larger picture: the problem today is largely that if you use the old tools and compile today, there is a compatibility issue (https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-from-scratch-13/problems-while-make-binutils-on-debian-vmware-4175549031/). 7yrs ago, the program was poorly written and has received numerous fixes! But we still come here to learn that. 

I hope that helps.

Comment: Also covered here: https://mudongliang.github.io/2017/07/01/binutils-215-error-array-type-has-incomplete-element-type.html But in earnest, you have developed significantly since then judging by your profile - I suspect you could help close out many of the basic ones as a service to the community. Otherwise, newbies like myself will fill the void.